# GWT panel fields data refresh delay on slow internet

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT 2.5.1.

In my GWT web app I have a ComplexPanel object which contains a set of fields(widgets). There are a suggested field (on panel) which gives me the opportunity to find object and info about it. Fields (10-15 of them) contain info about that object.

The problem is when user (client side) has a slow internet connection, fields on form are updated with a delay. And if in moment of delay user click 'Save' button (AsyncCallback), old data (which is not updated) posted to the server.

How it works:
1. Server receive callback from the form and start to processing the data.
2. Server refresh all the fields with new data and end the works.
3. Javascript updating the data on form using about 10 requests. 
But: internet is slow and one part of data is refreshed and other no. 
4. User click SAVE and mixed data goes to the server.

I need to know (from server side) when all the field are refreshed on client side and server can proceed with a next post request.

Thanks in any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a validation check on click of the save button. There are several things you can do as per your requirement. I have listed one way to validate it.

1. Set a flag before making the async call as *false*. For instance, `isLoaded = false`
2. Once you have all the fields just update it to true, i.e. `isLoaded = true`
3. On save button handler check for `isLoaded` flag. If *false*, prompt a message, else save.

**Update:**

You can count the number of response received. You know that you will get 10 response. So for every response received increment a counter. Activate save only if you have all 10 response recieved.

For a clean way to do this, use [gwt-async-future](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-async-future/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The real problem is that I don't know (from server side) when all the fields are updated on client side.

How it works:
1. Server receive callback from the form and start to processing the data.
2. Server refresh all the fields with new data and end the works.
3. Javascript updating the data on form using about 10 requests. 
But: internet is slow and one part of data is refreshed and other no. 
4. User click SAVE and mixed data goes to the server.

I need to know (from server side) when all the field are refreshed on client side.